# why wont my font color work

Tags: html, css, fonts, colors

Here is my css sheet i dont know why my font colors isn't working. Please help me out.

```
body {background-color: #d3d3d3;
      font-color; #FF0000;
      font-family: Calibre;
      text-align center;}}
h1   {background-color: #FFFFFF;
      font-color; #FF0000;
      font-family: Calibre;
      text-align center;}
h2   {background-color: #FFFFFF;
      font-color; #FF0000;
      font-family: Calibre;
      text-align center;}
h3   {background-color: #FFFFFF;
     font-color; #FF0000;
      font-family: Calibre;
      text-align center;}
p    {color; #FF0000;
      font-family: Calibre;
      font-size: .90em;
      text-indent: 3em; }    

.nav {font-weight:normal ;
      font-size: .9em; } 

#footer {font-color: #333333;
         font-size: .75em;
         font-style: italic;}
#wrapper {width: 80%;
         margin-left: auto;
         margin-right: auto;}
#Contact {font-family Times new Roman;
         font-size: .75em;
         font-style: bold;}
```

ps these are the errrors i got.

2   body    Value Error : color Parse Error color
2   body    Parse Error #FF0000;
5       Parse Error [: Calibre; text-align center;}} h1]
10  h2  Value Error : color Parse Error color
10  h2  Parse Error #FF0000;
13      Parse Error [: Calibre; text-align center;} h3]
17  p   Value Error : color Parse Error color
17  p   Parse Error #FF0000;
22      Parse Error [: Calibre; font-size: .90em; text-indent: 3em; }   .nav]
31  #Contact    Value Error : font-family Parse Error Times new Roman
33  #Contact    Value Error : font-style bold is not a font-style value : bold

Answer (score 2):

There are typos:

1. `font-color; #FF0000;` doesn't exist, should be `color: #f00;`
2. `color: #FF0000;` instead of `color; #FF0000; /* change ; for : */`
3. doesn't cause Parse error, but the font is `Calibri`, not `Calibre`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
#footer { color: #F00; }
```

This should work

Answer (score 0):

Set the font color of a text element like this:

```
h1{
color:#ff0000;
}
```